# Confidence interval of applying multiple odds ratios

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, odds-ratio

I use a scale (like the Framingham risk scale) to predict the probability of a binary clinical outcome. I used logistic regression to predict p for each scale score. The scale does not account for all risk factors. I calculate the outcome odds ratios (ORs) for those factors. I assume these other risk factors are independent.

I want to predict whether a patient's risk exceeds a defined threshold. I take the p corresponding to their score on the scale. I propose to convert the p to an odds and multiply it by each OR in succession. Is that a reasonable proposal?

Now I also want to predict whether the patient's risk p exceeds the threshold by a credible margin of error. I calculate 1-tailed confidence intervals for each OR. I take the odds of a 1-tailed lower limit of the original p. I propose to multiply those odds by the lower limit of each OR in succession. Should I set a lower confidence level for serial ORs, like p x n, where n = # of ORs, sort of a backward Bonferroni correction? Is this a reasonable proposal?

I want to give non-statistician clinicians a fairly easy way to adjust patients' risk predictions for factors not accounted for by the scale.